# Unix shell script to find string in a file then append by adding characters or number

Tags: bash, shell, unix, solaris

Is anyone can help me to add zeros in a string within the file?

For example: I have test.dat and it contains like below:

1   FirstName   LastName  A   +2015042113:00:00000285000FSCRD    INV 0
2   FirstName   LastName  B   +2015042220:00:00000331000SSESA    INV 0

And I would like to create a shell script to edit one of the string in the fie, by inserting three (3) zeros in the middle of the string.

So the output expected will be: I bold the added three zeros as below.

01   FirstName   LastName  A   +2015042113:00:00**000**000285000FSCRD    INV 0

02   FirstName   LastName  B   +2015042220:00:PM**000**000331000SSESA    INV 0

Comment: Can you _define_ where you want to add the zeros?

Comment: Assuming this is tab-delimited, and that the fifth field contains a fixed-length date stamp at the beginning, `awk -F '\t' '{ $5=substr($5, 1, 17) "000" substr($5, 18) } 1' file` would do what you are asking.

Comment: In your second example you add `PM0` instead of `000`. Please clarify.

Comment: @Ohad Eytan -- i highllited it in bold.

Comment: @tripleee -- thanks but its not tab-delimited but spaces. Please advise. Appreciate your reponse.

Comment: I saw the example, I'm looking for **definition**

Comment: @jiliagre -- yes it is AM or PM. after the colon: is the 12 hr time convention and after that is to add three zeros

Comment: Your question is unclear. You wish to add the `PM` or just the zeros?

Comment: @triplee  Hi.  It is space delimited. The next challenge is most of the time the FirstName has two string like John Adam and the fifth field or $5 would not be same position.  Any thoughts?  thanks in advance

Comment: @Ohad Eytan. Sorry I misunderstood you.  Basically after 17th position is to add the three zeros. For 1st example is from +2015042111:43:AM00028500000SSDD  to +2015042111:43:AM00000028500000SSDD  or2nd Example is from +2016011216:13:000000840000NEEEE to +2016011216:13:00000000840000NEEEE

Comment: You accepted a reply that doesn't match the question as it is expressed. PM is inserted to the expected result without being present in the source data, not to mention 20:00PM is dubious. Please at least correct the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed "s/\(+[0-9]\{10\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[A-Z0-9]\{2\}\)\([A-Z0-9]\{16\}\)/\1000\2/"
```

This `sed` command is to match the whole fifth field and then insert the three zeros. This would be more robust (in comparison to a shorter `regex`) to prevent replacing other parts of the line.

If there is a specification for the fifth field, it is possible to make the `regex` even stronger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` with `regex`:

```
sed 's/\(:..:..\)/\1000/' test.dat
```

it looks for the pattern `:..:..` (dot is any character, so it look for "*colon*,*any char*,*any char*,*colon*,*any char*,*any char*") and add 3 zeros to it

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
awk -F : '{print $1":"$2":"substr($3,1,2)"000"substr($3,3)}' test.dat
```

or

```
 sed -r -e 's/^.*:../&000/' test.dat
```

Comment: @M Dogru - the $5 would be an issue if the FirstName has two name like 'John Adam' and the file is not tab delimited but space. Any idea?  thanks for your response. this  pattern matching is really challenging I would say.

Comment: @Neo: I changed FS as  : Maybe this can help you;

Comment: M. Dogru - Looks it gonna work. im hitting illegal operation. I need to update my shell on some bin calling -r in my solaris 10. Thanks much!!